# SaltStack macros and environment variables

Tags: macros, environment-variables, salt-stack

I'm trying to create a formula to manage MySQL accounts on multiple database servers. I'm trying to re-use a macro from a `macro.sls` file, and use environment variables to specify connection settings. However, putting environment files in the state files for each database server doesn't work; it only works when I put them in the `macro.sls` file. This is not desired since I want to be able to update users on multiple database servers at once. See below:

```
# Example of "db_user" macro in mysql_user-mgmt/macro.sls
{%- macro db_user(user, password_hash, require_state="None") %}
{{ user }}:
  mysql_user.present:
    - connection_charset: {{ db_charset }}
    - connection_host: {{ db_host }}
    - connection_pass: {{ db_pass }}
    - connection_port: {{ db_port }}
    - connection_user: {{ db_user }}
    - host: "%"
    - password_hash: "{{ password_hash }}"
  {%- if require_state != "None" %}
    - require:
      - {{ require_state }}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Example db-server1.sls state file using macro

```
# My mysql_user-mgmt/db-server1.sls file
{%- import "mysql_user-mgmt/macro.sls" as macro -%}
{%- set db_charset = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_CHAR') -%}
{%- set db_host    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_HOST') -%}
{%- set db_pass    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_PASS') -%}
{%- set db_port    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_PORT') -%}
{%- set db_user    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_USER') -%}

{{ macro.db_user("someUser", "<MYSQL HASHED PASSWORD>") }}
```

...and the output then I try to run the `salt-call state.sls mysql_user-mgmt.db-server1` command

```
# Output of running `salt-call state.sls mysql_user-mgmt.db-server1`
local:
    - Rendering SLS 'base:mysql_user-mgmt.db-server1' failed: Jinja variable 'db_charset' is undefined
      /var/cache/salt/minion/files/base/mysql_user-mgmt/macro.sls(4):
      ---
      {%- macro db_user(user, password_hash, require_state="None") %}
      {{ user }}:
        mysql_user.present:
          - connection_charset: {{ db_charset }}    <======================
          - connection_host: {{ db_host }}
          - connection_pass: {{ db_pass }}
          - connection_port: {{ db_port }}
          - connection_user: {{ db_user }}
          - host: "%"
      [...]
      ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you should do is to pass variables as a parameters to the marco like this:

```
{%- macro db_user(
   user,
   password_hash,
   db_charset,
   db_host,
   db_pass,
   db_port,
   db_user,
   require_state="None"
) %}
{{ user }}:
  mysql_user.present:
    - connection_charset: {{ db_charset }}
    - connection_host: {{ db_host }}
    - connection_pass: {{ db_pass }}
    - connection_port: {{ db_port }}
    - connection_user: {{ db_user }}
    - host: "%"
    - password_hash: "{{ password_hash }}"
  {%- if require_state != "None" %}
    - require:
      - {{ require_state }}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

and then call a macro like this:

```
{%- import "mysql_user-mgmt/macro.sls" as macro -%}
{%- set db_charset = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_CHAR') -%}
{%- set db_host    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_HOST') -%}
{%- set db_pass    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_PASS') -%}
{%- set db_port    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_PORT') -%}
{%- set db_user    = salt['environ.get']('SERVER1_DB_USER') -%}
{{ macro.db_user(
   "someUser",
   "<MYSQL HASHED PASSWORD>",
   "db_charset",
   "db_host",
   "db_pass",
   "db_port",
   "db_user"
) }}
```

I'm writing this code from my head - so there might be some errors in syntax, but the logic should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

@alexK Thanks for the answer, that helped greatly! In the end I defined `connection`as a YAML map, and let the macro split it up into the corresponding settings.

db-server1.sls:

```
{%- import "mysql_user-mgmt/macro.sls" as macro -%}

{%- load_yaml as connection -%}
charset: {{ salt['environ.get']('PRODUCTION_DB_CHAR') }}
host: {{ salt['environ.get']('PRODUCTION_DB_HOST') }}
pass: {{ salt['environ.get']('PRODUCTION_DB_PASS') }}
port: {{ salt['environ.get']('PRODUCTION_DB_PORT') }}
user: {{ salt['environ.get']('PRODUCTION_DB_USER') }}
{%- endload -%}

{{ macro.db_user("someUser", "<MYSQL HASHED PASSWORD>", connection) }}
```

macro.sls

```
{%- macro db_user(user, password_hash, connection, require_state=False) %}
{{ user }}:
  mysql_user.present:
    - connection_charset: {{ connection.charset }}
    - connection_host: {{ connection.host }}
    - connection_pass: {{ connection.pass }}
    - connection_port: {{ connection.port }}
    - connection_user: {{ connection.user }}
    - host: "%"
    - password_hash: "{{ password_hash }}"
  {%- if require_state %}
    - require:
      - {{ require_state }}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Same thing in the end. Thanks again!